# An unknown error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again. While using firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

**Is Firebase storage service having a disruption?**

While working with it earlier today this error in red popped up at the top:

> An unknown error occurred. Please refresh the page and try again

And it has not yet gone away. I have encounters this one other time but shortly after it went away, this time it is not.

I have:

- Tried different networks including VPNs
- tried signing in and out of my google account

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for this kind of question.  Contact Firebase support directly if you think there is an outage.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Outages are reported on https://status.firebase.google.com/. Nothing is reported there, and when I just checked a few of my projects they also worked without problems. Make sure that you have no plugins/extensions in your browser that might be blocking this traffic. If the problem persists for you, report it to support indeed as Doug commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my email back form Firebase support I was recommended to try the following:

- Try to activate this feature using an incognito window/private window and disable all browser extensions
- Try using a different browser (and make sure browser is supported)
- Verify if there are any other programs that might be blocking your connection such as antivirus, proxy or firewall. If yes, try to disable them.
- Connect using a different network.
- Connect using a different device.
- Check the Developer Tools Console for any errors.
- For Safari: 
  Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Check "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
  Develop > Show Web Inspector > Console Tab

If none work, contact support.