# Cannot access Firebase Storage after creating storage bucket in GCP Console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I noticed that Firebase wouldn't let me create a storage bucket asia-southeast1 so I upgraded my plan to blaze, went to the GCP console and created a bucket from there.

I did the same for Firestore and it's working fine.
However, after I created the storage bucket in GCP, and I came back to the Firebase console to access Firebase Cloud Storage, I keep receiving this error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how creating a bucket in the GCP console may affect your Firebase project (unless you created a bucket named `<your-project-name>.appspot.com`).

These kinds of errors normally happen when a certain quota has been reached, and is usually solved **by upgrading your project to a paid plan**.

As you have already upgraded your project, please bear into account that **billing updates usually take some time to be processed**. Waiting a few hours, or maybe  checking the next day whether your project has been successfully upgraded should do the trick.

If that does not help, verify whether you have actually upgraded your project - You can check that [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview?purchaseBillingPlan=metered). The Blaze Plan button should be grayed out with the message `Current Plan`.

The answer provided to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412163/) question may also be of help:

> Try to activate this feature using an incognito window/private window
> and disable all browser extensions
>
> Try using a different browser (and make sure browser is supported)
>
> Verify if there are any other programs that might be blocking your
> connection such as antivirus, proxy or firewall. If yes, try to
> disable them.
>
> Connect using a different network.
>
> Connect using a different device.
>
> Check the Developer Tools Console for any errors.
>
> For Safari: Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Check "Show Develop menu
> in menu bar" Develop > Show Web Inspector > Console Tab

If none of these approaches work for you, consider contacting Firebase Support [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by using the command to work on it using

```
firebase init storage
```

This would create the storage after that it would add a storage.rule in which you can update to your liking in your project .
Then you run this command

```
firebase deploy --only storage
```

This would initialize the Storage

If you are still having issues check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750337 which was also provided by firebase for me to fix the error